# Cannot delete a folder

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, external-hdd, error-handling

I have Segate backup + 1TB external HDD recently since 1 month i am unable to copy the files effectively sometimes the copying is 10 kb/s like that. and sometimes iam getting error like  `Input/output error` & `Error splicing file: Input/output error`
 and when i check my External HDD with disk utility i had found

```
Disk is OK, 438 bad sectors (37° C / 99° F)
```

and i tried checking with  `sudo smartctl --all /dev/sdb`

```
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

and every other files i am able accessing all are good but iam unable to store the files its very hard to coping the files and i have one folder when i tried to delete using inodes, and rm-rf, and manual shift-delete iam getting error like `Error removing file: No such file or directory` but actually i am seeing that directory.

please tell is there any solution how to fix those bad blocks?

And i had removed my HDD without `safely remove drive` or ejecting so many times.is any problem caused because of this?

Is it a hardware problem or Filesystem problem ? can i use my HDD further without copying and deleting To save MY DATA until i get another NEW DISK?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely a combination of hardware issues and damaged directory structures from not ejecting the disk properly. If Disk Utility is unable to repair any filesystem damage, replacing the disk is the best option. Quit using the disk until you have a replacement. Recover the data you can to the new drive. You may be able to get some additional life out of the old drive with a full erase & reformat which will map out bad blocks, but I would hesitate using it for any critical data storage.

Comment: can i just use it to read the data only,but not for Copying and storing files.? because i have most used files are there i have to use them everyday

Comment: I would not use it. Many things are written to the disk even when you are only reading files from it. Continuing to use it only increases the chance that directory damage will increase making file recovery more difficult.

Comment: how to recover the whole hdd when i get these type of problems

Comment: how to check my day day to perfomance. like errors is there any tool in linux.

Comment: Disk Utility can run filesystem checks, SMART tests and so on. For recovery, I would clone the disk using `dd` or Clonezilla and run recovery tools on the duped drive.